# Excel VBA: Optimizing code to delete rows based on a duplicate in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to come up with a lean and error-proofed macro to delete rows containing duplicate values in a column A. I have two solutions and both have their advantages. None of them are exactly what I want.

**I need rows containing duplicates deleted but leaving the last row that contained the duplicate.**

1. This one is awesome. It has no loop and works instantaneously. The problem is that it deletes subsequent rows containing duplicates hence leaving the first occurrence of the duplicate (And I need the last/ or second - most show up only twice)

   `Sub Delete()
       ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
   End Sub`
2. This one goes from the bottom and deletes duplicates. It lasts longer than the first one ( I have around 6k rows) But the issue with this one is that it doesnt delete them all. Some duplicates are left and they are deleted after I run the same code again. Even smaller number of duppes is still left. Basically need to run it up to 5 times and then I end up with clean list.

   `

   Sub DeleteDup()

   ```
     Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long, rowschecktodelete As Long

     LastRowcheck = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
       With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n1, 1)
         If Cells(n1, 1) = Cells(n1 + 1, 1) Then
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n1, 1).Select
           Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
      End With
     Next n1

     End Sub
   ```

`
Is there a way to improve any of these to work well or is there a better solution? Any info is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the sheet sorted on column A when the code is run?

Comment: Hi. Yes. Column A is list of numbers, but they are formatted as text. So maybe a line to make it number values is missing. Still I get the same results/issues whether I turn it into # or not. These numbers go from smallest to largest hence the duplicates are one under another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is right, but remember that when you delete rows, `Cells(n1 + 1, 1)` isn't going to be the same thing as it was before you deleted a row.  The solution is to simply reverse the loop and test rows from bottom to top:

```
Sub DeleteDup()
    Dim last As Long
    Dim current As Long
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With sheet
        last = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For current = last To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(current + 1, 1).Value = .Cells(current, 1).Value Then
                .Rows(current).Delete
            End If
        Next current
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that you can use the loop counter to index `.Rows` instead of using the `Selection` object to improve performance fairly significantly.  Also, if you grab a reference to the `Worksheet` and toss the whole thing in a `With` block you don't have to continually dereference `Worksheets("Sheet1")`, which will also improve performance.

If it still runs too slow, the next step would be to flag rows for deletion, sort on the flag, delete the entire flagged range in one operation, then sort back to the original order.  I'm guessing the code above should be fast enough for ~6K rows though.

Comment: Like a charm. I started learning VBA recently due to need and improved a lot of dumb repetitive things but still need to get into routine with using some of the stuff you mentioned and revise lots of my code. Hence I really really appreciate explaining what you did and how you cut down the time. It works and was done in cca 3 seconds. Thank you for a prompt answer mate.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to delete all rows at once. Also to increase speed, you better do your checks with variables and not with the real cell values like this:

```
Sub DeleteDup()

  Dim LastRowcheck As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim rows_to_delete As Range
  Dim range_to_check As Variant

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRowcheck = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    range_to_check = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowcheck).Values

    For i = 1 To LastRowcheck - 1
      If range_to_check(i, 1) = range_to_check(i + 1, 1) Then
        If rows_to_delete Is Nothing Then
          Set rows_to_delete = .Cells(i, 1)
        Else
          Set rows_to_delete = Union(.Cells(i, 1), rows_to_delete)
        End If
      End If
    Next n1
  End With

  rows_to_delete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```